# Jquery Load function takes a lot time to refresh or load data. How I can make it faster

Tags: php, jquery, load

I have several parts in my web application Where I load data via Jquery Load function.
It works absolutely as I want. But the issue is, it takes too longer time to load the data from database.

My code sketches are given below;

```
<div id="Records"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Records").load('recs.php');
});
</script>
```

And here is the `recs.php`

```
<table>
<?php
include 'db.php';

$GetAllRecords = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT * FROM `table`");
while($rc = mysqli_fetch_array($GetAllRecords)){
echo '<tr>
<td>'.$rc["col1"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col2"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col3"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col4"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col5"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col6"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col7"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col8"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col9"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col10"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col11"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col12"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col13"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col14"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col15"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col16"].'</td>
<td>'.$rc["col17"].'</td>
</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: This hugely depends on the number of entries you have in that table. A normal server should be able to run that fairly quickly, can you edit your post and add what your table looks like?

Comment: Table is Good. Simple records as usual.

Comment: And My Server is also good. No issue at all. it is a VPS server.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many factors affecting your performance. Slow server, large number of rows in the table? However, if there is a large number of results maybe the perceived rendering time could be having an impact.

You seem to be missing your TABLE tags within your #Records DIV.

```
<div id="Records"><table></table></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#Records table").load('recs.php');
});
</script>
```

Comment: No this is the same thing.
i have the VPS Server a Good one. Yes, this is true that Table has too many records but not more than 500 at a time.

Comment: 500 records can be quite heavy for page rendering alone, even without regard to how complex (or not) the query being executed might be. 

How long is it actually taking to render? And, is this a user-facing feature, or only an admin feature?

Comment: It is user-facing feature. And sometimes it takes 1 minute to load the data.

Comment: Maybe try pagination, a progress spinner, infinite scrolling, or caching.